# How can I get Vim to show documentation of a C/C++ function?

Tags: autocompletion

Most editors have a feature like when you press some keys by placing caret over a function, it pops the documentation of that function along with number and type of arguments that function takes.

I was wondering whether Vim offers such support. For example, while coding in C, I use a built in function `qsort()`. Since I am not sure about type and number of arguments it takes, I would like to know it without escaping Vim. Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure this is exactly what you want, but if you give the right value to the option `'keywordprg'` (the name of a program which can handle the documentation for the language you want), then by hitting `K` on a keyword (which can be the name of a function), you should get the info you want. For example, if you install `cppman` (https://github.com/aitjcize/cppman) and add an autocmd inside your vimrc such as `autocmd FileType cpp setlocal keywordprg=cppman`, then `cppman` should handle the documentation inside a c++ buffer. Not tested though.

Comment: @saginaw While `cppman` is an excellent suggestion, if you have the C and C++ manpages (`manpages-posix-dev` and `libstdc++-X.Y-doc` packages on Debian-based systems) installed, plain old `man` should work.

Answer (score 21):

For C, pressing `K` on the keyword will pull up the built-in manpage directly. For instance, place the cursor on the `printf` keyword:

```
printf("Hello, %s!", foo);
```

Now press `K` (upper case K) and the manpage for `printf` should appear in VIM:

```
NAME
   printf - format and print data

SYNOPSIS
   printf FORMAT [ARGUMENT]...
   printf OPTION

DESCRIPTION
   Print ARGUMENT(s) according to FORMAT, or execute according to OPTION:

   --help display this help and exit

   --version
          output version information and exit

   FORMAT controls the output as in C printf.  Interpreted sequences are:

   \"     double quote
   \\     backslash

   ... It continues for quite a few scrollable pages
```

This seems to work out of the box in all Debian-derived distros that I've tried it on, no specific configuration required.

Comment: That's the manpage of [`printf(1)`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?&query=printf) the command, not [`printf(3)`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=printf&sektion=3) the function. In any case, the C function manpages are from [`manpages-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/manpages-dev/filelist), which is usually installed by default, but not always, and POSIX functions are in [`manpages-posix-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/manpages-posix-dev/filelist) - usually not installed by default, neither is C++ documentation (`libstdc++-X.Y-doc`).

Comment: See @PiCTo's [excellent new answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26502/343) for details on how to get this feature to open the desired man page.

Answer (score 14):

If you can set up [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe), it supports C, C++, JavaScript, Go and some other languages. Here's it in action:

[image]
[image]

It's a bit annoying to [install](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#installation), and once it's installed you need to [configure it for C and C++](https://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/#c-family-semantic-completion-engine-usage) by creating a `.ycm_extra_conf.py`. I lifted one from [this repo](https://github.com/rasendubi/dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/.ycm_extra_conf.py), and got this effect.

Comment: "t's a bit annoying to install,"... That's an understatement.  Still, it is very good. ^_~

Comment: Is there any way to force the completions pop-up to remain opened while the function arguments are typed? For example, as soon as you type the first letter of the first argument `qsort(a`, the pop-up window disappears, making it difficult to remember the next arguments.

Comment: But it just shows the prototype of the function. How to make it show its doxygen comments (like Eclipse does with javadocs)? I mean parameters, output, notes, refs...

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator One thing I use heavily in Python is `YcmCompleter GoTo`, which usually sends you to where the function/class was defined in code.  That is the line just above the docstring, which lists everything you asked for.  I am not sure if the inline commenting is in the same place in C/Java/C++.

Answer (score 7):

If you want proper *documentation*, the plugin in saginaw's comment seems to cover your C++ needs. I don't know of a generic one but you can probably find alternatives for other languages on vim.org.

---

If…

- your code is already indexed with ctags,
- your index also includes the standard library,
- and all you want is a *hint*,

you can use `<C-w>}` to open the definition of the keyword under your cursor in a preview window. YMMV, of course.

See `:help preview-window`, `:help tags` and `:help ctags`.

---

You can also use Vim's built-in "include-search" functionality: press `[i` to print the "signature" of the word under the cursor in the command-line:

[image: [i]

See `:help include-search`.

Comment: `[i` is weird. It works for `stdlib.h` and `qsort`, but not `cstdlib` and `std::qsort` or just `qsort`.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with the nomenclature as I am/was `<C-w>` means `CTRL-W` Which is the nomenclature used in the `:help` files. You may then use `:pc` to close the preview window.

Answer (score 5):

Using only vanilla Vim and complementary to [`tags`-based solutions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6229/23696),
`K` calls `'keywordprg'` (defaults to `man`) on the word under the cursor (in normal mode) or the current selection (in visual mode) and displays the output. As recommended in [another answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6232/23696), this can be used to refer to the documentation **for standard functions and variables** (some IDEs might blur the line between documentation for standard and non-standard libraries, you will certainly not get the latter from `K`/`man`).

However, as missed by that answer, pressing `K` on `printf` will output the documentation of `printf(1)` ("the command `printf`"), not `printf(3)` ("the function `printf`" from the C Standard Library) which you are probably after. See [*What do the numbers in a man page mean?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3586) for more details about this distinction. Practically speaking, it is the output of `man [-s] 1 printf` (to which `man printf` defaults) instead of `man [-s] 3 printf`.

As stated in its documentation (`:help kp`), `K` takes a count:

```
'keywordprg' 'kp'   string  (default "man" or "man -s")

    Program to use for the |K| command.
    [...]
    When "man", "man -s" or an Ex command is used, Vim will automatically
    translate a count for the "K" command and pass it as the first
    argument.  For "man -s" the "-s" is removed when there is no count.
```

Therefore, you can get the documentation for `printf(3)` from `3K`.

As this is likely to be the desired behaviour every time `K` is used, I see 2 options:

- modify `'keywordprg'` to be `man [-s] 3`:

  ```
  setlocal keywordprg+=\ 3
  ```
- remap `K` to be `3K` in modes where `K` calls `'kp'`:

  ```
  nnoremap <buffer> K 3K
  vnoremap <buffer> K 3K
  ```

and, as this behaviour is only useful in C code, add your choice among the solutions above to a `ftplugin` in your `after-directory` (*e.g.* to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim`). Also note that, according to [@muru's comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6228#comment9680_6232), the packages containing the manpages might have to be installed beforehand.

Finally, as [mentioned by @kyticka](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13132/23696), for C++ (although also helpful in C), you may use a similar approach by replacing `man` with [`cppman`](https://github.com/aitjcize/cppman) as your `'kp'` *e.g.* in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim`:

```
set keywordprg=cppman
```

Alternatively, [`cppman`](https://github.com/aitjcize/cppman) can be used to cache entries from [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com) as (offline) `man` pages and `man` can be set up to read those pages, allowing you to use the default to access documentation for the C++ Standard Library from `man` and, by extension, from the default `'kp'`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned pressing `K` on the keyword works by searching a man page. For getting C++ man pages you may try https://github.com/aitjcize/cppman (it gets "man pages" from cplusplus.com and cppreference.com).

Answer (score 1):

Vim's C/C++ file type comes with a decent omnicompletion function, which supports "preview" functionality.  So add "preview" to your completeopt option and see a function signature when you do insert mode completion.

In normal mode, you could CTRL+W } to open the function declaration in the preview window manually.

Answer (score 0):

Install YouCompleteMe. When you place the cursor over an identifier, enter `YcmCompleter GetDoc` command to get the doc in a little preview window at the bottom. It works across many languages like python and c/c++.

Youcompleteme also displays the preview window during its autocomplete feature. You can customize the behavior of the doc preview with `g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion` variable.